# Grunt compiles handlebars differently—and I can’t load the compiled template

Tags: javascript, templates, gruntjs, handlebars.js

I'm messing around with Handlebars and I'm trying to precompile templates using Grunt. Its output, though, is different from the regular handlebars cli output.

Grunt gives the following output:

```
this["tpl"] = this["tpl"] || {};
this["tpl"]["templates"] = this["tpl"]["templates"] || {};
this["tpl"]["templates"]["assets/src/templates/test.hbs"] = Handlebars.template({"compiler":[6,">= 2.0.0-beta.1"],"main":function(depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
    var helper, functionType="function", helperMissing=helpers.helperMissing, escapeExpression=this.escapeExpression;
    return "<h1>"
        + escapeExpression(((helper = (helper = helpers.title || (depth0 != null ? depth0.title : depth0)) != null ? helper : helperMissing),(typeof helper === functionType ? helper.call(depth0, {"name":"title","hash":{},"data":data}) : helper)))
        + "</h1>\n<p>"
        + escapeExpression(((helper = (helper = helpers.body || (depth0 != null ? depth0.body : depth0)) != null ? helper : helperMissing),(typeof helper === functionType ? helper.call(depth0, {"name":"body","hash":{},"data":data}) : helper)))
        + "</p>";
},"useData":true});
```

The regular output is this:

```
(function() {
    var template = Handlebars.template, templates = Handlebars.templates = Handlebars.templates || {};
    templates['test.hbs'] = template({"compiler":[6,">= 2.0.0-beta.1"],"main":function(depth0,helpers,partials,data) {
        var helper, alias1=helpers.helperMissing, alias2="function", alias3=this.escapeExpression;
        return "<h1>"
            + alias3(((helper = (helper = helpers.title || (depth0 != null ? depth0.title : depth0)) != null ? helper : alias1),(typeof helper === alias2 ? helper.call(depth0,{"name":"title","hash":{},"data":data}) : helper)))
            + "</h1>\n<p>"
            + alias3(((helper = (helper = helpers.body || (depth0 != null ? depth0.body : depth0)) != null ? helper : alias1),(typeof helper === alias2 ? helper.call(depth0,{"name":"body","hash":{},"data":data}) : helper)))
            + "</p>";
    },"useData":true});
})();
```

Loading my template from Grunt, like this, doesn't work:

```
$.getJSON('assets/src/data/data.json', function(data) {
    var testTemplate = tpl['test.hbs'];
    var testHtml = testTemplate(data);
    $('body').append(testHtml);
});
```

While loading my template like this works:

```
<script>
    $.getJSON('assets/src/data/data.json', function(data) {
        var testTemplate = Handlebars.templates['test.hbs'];
        var testHtml = testTemplate(data);
        $('body').append(testHtml);
    });
</script>
```

My Gruntfile is as follows:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
'use strict';
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    handlebars: {
        compile: {
            options: {
                namespace: 'tpl.templates',
            },
            files: {
                "assets/build/templates/alltemplates.js": "assets/src/templates/*.hbs"
            }
        }
    },
// etc.
```

And this is the file structure:

[image: Folder structure of the project]

Comment: When you say "loading my template from Grunt doesn't work", what exactly is the issue?

Comment: @Whymarrh Well, I'm not sure. Basically I’d get a blank screen and the following error message: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I just figured out that the problem is in the namespace option in the gruntfile.

Removing the namespace, which results in the default namespace 'JST' and then inspecting the JST object in the console gave the first hint:

```
Object {assets/src/templates/test.hbs: function}
```

So the correct way to call the template would then be:

```
var testTemplate = JST['assets/src/templates/test.hbs'];
```

So with a namespace the gruntfile would read:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    'use strict';

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        handlebars: {
            compile: {
                options: {
                    namespace: 'tpl',
                },
                files: {
                    "assets/build/templates/alltemplates.js": "assets/src/templates/*.hbs"
                }
            }
        },
```

(etc.)

And the way to call the template:

```
var testTemplate = tpl['assets/src/templates/test.hbs'];
```